# Image Lazy Loading Ionic 3 not working in my project

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

[link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-lazyload-image)

[link2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic-image-loader)
 i follow both link but image lazy load not working in my project ,please suggestion

Comment: can you show what you have tried

Answer (score 1):

Here is working [Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-progressive-image-loader-c8jdmm?file=providers/lorem/lorem.ts)

image list api
https://picsum.photos/list

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public imageloader: Lorem) {
    this.loadMyImages();   
  }

  loadMyImages()
  {
    this.loadingLoremPicsList = true;
    this.loremList = [];
    this.albumList = [];
    this.imageloader.getMyPics().subscribe(
        data => {
            this.loremList = data;
            this.albumList = this.loremList.splice(this.getRandomInt(0, 700), 12);
            console.dirxml(this.loremList);
            this.loadingLoremPicsList = false;
        },
        err =>
        {

        }
      )
  }
```

in provider .ts

```
  private my_lorem_pics: string = "https://picsum.photos/list";

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
  }

  getMyPics()
  {
   return this.http.get(this.my_lorem_pics);
  }
```